# .index() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

You see I'm trying to manipulate some elements when comparing their index.
The problem is my index isn't assigned with int value but stays undefined.

```
$(function(){
  var i;
  $("a").click
  (
    function()
    {
      i = $("a").index(this);                     
      $(".textholder div:eq(i)").slideUp();
      $(".textholder div:eq(i+1)").css('top', '-210px');
      return false;
      }
  );
  alert(i);
});
```

I'm also open for any remarks about my syntax and algorithm!

Any suggestions?
Thank you all

Comment: Could you post your mark-up as well? Perhaps a demo at a collaborative site such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: I'm not a jQuery guru, but I'd try passing the index() function `$(this)` instead of `this` (I think it requires a jQuery object). I'm not sure about it though, so posting this as a comment. [edit] OK, I was wrong :D

Comment: @mingos, we all live and learn, +1 for editing to 'fess up, rather than just deleting the comment =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You alert `i` before anything is clicked. When you click something, the only bit that's executed is from the line `function()` to the line `return false;` So it's no wonder that `i` is undefined.

If you want to see the value of `i` when it is set, move the `alert(i)` line (or even better, change it to `console.log()`) to below the `i = $("a").index(this);` line.

Comment: I hadn't caught that, +1, well spotted =)

Comment: @David - there's only *so* many wrong things you can spot about a piece of code at once!

Comment: 10x Now it returns value however my divs isn't moving but that's quite different matter :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure that it's your only problem, but:

```
$(".textholder div:eq(i)").slideUp();
$(".textholder div:eq(i+1)").css('top', '-210px');
```

Should be:

```
$(".textholder div:eq(" + i + ")").slideUp();
$(".textholder div:eq(" + i+1 + ")").css('top', '-210px');
```

Otherwise the `i` won't be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

The `i` variable will not get *interpolated* within the string, bring it outside.

```
$(function(){
  var i;
  $("a").click
  (
    function()
    {
      i = $("a").index(this);                     
      $(".textholder div:eq(" + i + ")").slideUp();
      $(".textholder div:eq(" + (i+1) + ")").css('top', '-210px');
      return false;
      }
  );
  alert(i);
});
```